# HTML STYLE MARGIN DISABLE FORM

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my menu on the left side and one text box with one option menu to search for my records which is inside the form on the right side. But it is not working when I margin the form to top in negative pixels.

Here is the code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ include file="header.jsp"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>SEARCH - VMS</title>

<style>
input[type=text]{
    width: 10%;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;

    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    color: #4f4f4f;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

input[type=submit],input[type=reset]{
     border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 12px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    }
</style>

</head>



<form name="search" method="post" action="SearchController?op=1">

<div style="margin-left: 500px;"> 
SELECT TYPE TO SEARCH DRIVER<br><br>

<select name="list">
<option>dname</option>
<option>dcontact</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="txtField">


<input type="submit" value="Search" name="search">
<input type="reset" value = "Reset">
</div>
</form>
<div style="margin-top: -118px;">
<%@ include file="menu.jsp" %>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>SEARCH - VMS</title>

<style>
input[type=text]{
width: 10%;
height: 20px;
padding: 5px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
margin-top: 5px;

border: 2px solid #ccc;
color: #4f4f4f;
font-size: 16px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type=submit],input[type=reset]{
 border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
background-color: #f6f6f6;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 12px;
height: 35px;
padding: 5px;
width: 100px;
}
form{display:block;
margin-top:-10px;}
</style>

</head>


<body>
<form name="search" method="post" action="SearchController?op=1">

<div> 
SELECT TYPE TO SEARCH DRIVER<br><br>

<select name="list">
<option>dname</option>
<option>dcontact</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="txtField">


<input type="submit" value="Search" name="search">
<input type="reset" value = "Reset">
</div>
</form>
<div>
 <%@ include file="menu.jsp" %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```